# FasterXML serialization without using field type in XML

Tags: java, xml, jackson, xml-serialization, fasterxml

I'm trying to achieve following XML:

```
<model>
    <entry>
        <key>A</key>
        <value>1</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>B</key>
        <value>2</value>
    </entry>
</model>
```

Closest *POJO* model I've got by experimenting with my code looks like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import org.junit.Test;

public class InsPersonFormTest {

    @JsonRootName("model")
    public static class Model extends ArrayList<Entry> {

        public Model(List<Entry> entries) { super(entries); }

        public List<Entry> getEntry() { return this; }
    }

    public static class Entry {

        String key;
        String value;

        public Entry(String key, String value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getKey() { return key; }

        public String getValue() { return value; }       
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSendPostRequest() throws JsonProcessingException {
        Model model = new Model(newArrayList(new Entry("A", "1"), new Entry("B", "2")));

        ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(model);

        assertThat(xml, equalTo(
                "<model>"
                + "<entry><key>A</key><value>1</value></entry>"
                + "<entry><key>B</key><value>2</value></entry>"
                + "</model>"));
    }
}
```

But it gives me

Expected:

`"<model><entry><key>A</key><value>1</value></entry><entry><key>B</key><value>2</value></entry></model>"`

but: was

`"<model><item><key>A</key><value>1</value></item><item><key>B</key><value>2</value></item></model>"`

How can I change `item` to `entry` or use simpliest POJO structure with more suitable `Map<String, String>` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make your `Model` class a subtype of `ArrayList`. Instead use composition

```
public static class Model {
    private ArrayList<Entry> entry;

    public Model(List<Entry> entries) {
        entry = entries; // or make a copy 
    }

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    public List<Entry> getEntry() {
        return entry
    }

}
```

`ArrayList` is a `List` and Jackson handles `List` in a managed way.

You'll need to add `JacksonXmlElementWrapper` so you can tell Jackson not to wrap the resulting XML.

You can then use

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(/* custom */)
```

to annotate `Entry` and add local name of the XML node and namespace value.

Comment: I've made `Model` class to be a subtipe of an `ArrayList` because of double wrapping in `<entry>` tag. If I did everything exactly as you advised, then unfortunatelly this situation comes back again. Here is an output: `<model><entry><entry><key>A</key><value>1</value></entry><entry><key>B</key><value>2</value></entry></entry></model>`. As you can see `<entry>` tag doubles again.

Comment: @ytterrr You're right. Added solution for that as well.

Comment: `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper` was key annotation to make it work. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried annotating the Entry class?

```
@JsonRootName("entry")
public static class Entry {

    String key;
    String value;

    public Entry(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() { return key; }

    public String getValue() { return value; }       
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your participation. Yes, I have tryed it - it seems that `@JsonRootName("entry")` doesn't helps in that case.